# Publish sessions without video in bigbluebutto

Tags: php, bigbluebutton

I would like to publish sessions of bigbluebutton without video.
In the sessions, users have enabled their webcams, but to publish the recorded sessions, I don't want to share their video.
In addition، is there anyway to publish only session moderatore video?
I have tried webcamsOnlyForModerator option but it doesn't work.

I have tried webcamsOnlyForModerator option but it doesn't work

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.